# Closure Library: good.net.XhrIo.send not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, google-closure-library

`goog.net.XhrIo.send` in Closure Library outputs "undefined" error in Safari v8.0.5, whereas it works fine on Chrome and FireFox.

What can I do to solve this error?
What are the possible causes?

Static Access

```
goog.net.XhrIo.send('filename.json', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getResponseJson());
});
```

Instance Access

```
var request = new goog.net.XhrIo();
var url = 'rest/search/test';
goog.events.listen(request, 'complete', function() {
    // etc
});
request.send(url,'GET');
```

`console.log(goog.net.XhrIo.send)`

- Safari: undefined
- Chrome: function (url, opt_callback, ...)
- FireFox: function (url, opt_callback, ...)

I've already tried

- clearing cache on Safari
- static access and instance access (both failed)
- using send() method on multiple pages (all failed)
- updating dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error was caused by "AdBlock" (Browser Extension).
After I turned it off, `good.net.XhrIo.send` worked on Safari.